# How do you add a global breakpoint in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode

I know how to do this in XCode 3, but just can't find how to add a global (as opposed to at a specific line) breakpoint in XCode 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good answer in the apple developer forums (paid account needed): https://devforums.apple.com/thread/68421

To summarise, you have to go to the breakpoints navigator (View->Navigators->Breakpoint Navigator), add a new symbolic breakpoint using the + button at the bottom left corner. To make this breakpoint global, you have to right click it and press "Move Breakpoint to -> User"