# How to test where is app crashing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have app that sometimes crashes in navigating through Navigation bar and in console log is no error except this ->

`(lldb)`

How can I check where is error?

Comment: First step would be adding global breakpoints to have your debugger stop upon exception throw. See this tread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825275/how-do-you-add-a-global-breakpoint-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode, go to Product > Edit Scheme > Diagnostics > Enable Zombie Object

Now run the app and check the console.

Comment: Excellent, that's it. Now It shows me exactly where the error was. Is it okay if I leave it on at all the time?

Comment: Since turning on Zombies means the memory zone occupied by the object will never get freed, there will be huge drag on the memory allocation. Therefore it's okay to use it when debugging, but you don't want to ship your product with this setting.

Answer (score 3):

try enable zombie objects from

produt>edit schems> enable zombi

Comment: Excellent, that's it. Now It shows me exactly where the error was. Is it okay if I leave it on at all the time?

Comment: yea ok but not when u deploy app to appstore

Comment: and more prefferabley never on a device, because this will aslo keep the relaesed objects in memory. that's y avoid it enabled when u want to deploy it into a device of sending it to appstore

Answer (score 3):

See [a recent answer I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501532/49658):

When the debugger stops, go to the "Debug Navigator" and make sure the slider on the bottom is all the way to the right.

Scan your eye down from the point at which the exception is thrown and you should eventually come to your own code. Click on the appropriate method/function name and the code will be opened in the editor.

[image]

[image]

If you don't see any of your own methods in the stack trace, the exception may have been passed through a `performSelector`-style call in which case the stack trace is gone. If this is the case, you may get better information by adding an "On Throw" exception break point. First switch to the "Breakpoint navigator":

[image]

Then click on the plus and choose "Add Exception breakpoint..."

[image]

Create an "On Throw" break point:

[image]

This will stop the debugger at the exact point the exception is thrown, and you get a better stack trace. It's a good idea to have an exception break point like this enabled all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Type bt at the lldb prompt and it will give you a stack trace telling where the app crashed.